# Access orders page with wget

Tags: magento2, security

people. My question may be simple but I can't find an answer. I want to be able to get the page source of my orders with a command. I plan something like
wget -user myUserName -password myPassword https://mywebsite.com/index.php/admin/admin/sales_order/index/key/somekey9sdf9s7978fds97s8fds9/
But this only downloads the admin login page. Thanks in advance.